# mono-service2 does not create a lock file on OSX

Tags: c#, .net, macos, mono, mono-service

I'm running OSX 10.9 with mono 3.2.4.

I have a simple app I would like to run as a Daemon but mono-service does not create a lock file with the PID in it. I have tried searching in /tmp and also the temp path I get when using:

```
Path.GetTempPath();
```

Which returned:

```
/var/folders/2r/ryt5sbkd6sl0h0jjvr28qybr0000gn/T/
```

But no luck. Is this maybe a bug in mono?

I have used `mono-service2 DaemonTest.exe` and `mono-service2 l:myLockFile.lock DaemonTest.exe` to start the daemon. The daemon itself runs because I can see the mono garbage collector running in my system monitor.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

try this 
mono-service2 -l:myLockFile.lock DaemonTest.exe

i think you just forgot a -

Answer (score 0):

according to the help. when -l is not specified the lock file goes to /tmp

typing `mono-service` or `mono-service2` without parameters will present this help.